# JAXB unmarshal callbacks not called with the Binder implementation of EclipseLink Moxy

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a problem with the [javax.xml.bind.Binder implementation of EclipseLink Moxy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/JAXBBinder.html): the [unmarshal callback methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) (afterUnmarshal in my case) annotated in my binding classes are never called when I unmarshal my objects from a DOM document instance.

The problem seems to be in the [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e28847/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLUnmarshaller.html) instance used by the Binder : the unmarshalListener, which is responsible for calling the callback methods, is always null. This code demonstrates the problem :

```
//Instantiate a JAXBContext
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class);

//Create a "standard" unmarshaller
JAXBUnmarshaller standardUnmarshaller = (JAXBUnmarshaller) context.createUnmarshaller();

//assertion is ok
assert standardUnmarshaller.getXMLUnmarshaller().getUnmarshalListener() != null;

//Create a Binder
XMLBinder xmlBinder = ((JAXBBinder) context.createBinder()).getXMLBinder();

//Use reflection tricks to get the unmarshaller (fest-reflect is used for conciseness)
XMLUnmarshaller binderUnmarshaller = Reflection.field("unmarshaller").ofType(XMLUnmarshaller.class).in(xmlBinder).get();

//assertion error here
assert binderUnmarshaller.getUnmarshalListener() != null;
```

This can’t be easily fixed, because [org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalListener](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/JAXBUnmarshalListener.html) can’t be instantiated without a javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller instance, which does not exist in the Binder context. There is no other XMLUnmarshalListener implementation available in Moxy to replace the JAXBUnmarshalListener.

I came up with this workaround, which consists in reusing the JAXBUnmarshalListener instance from a "standard" JAXB unmarshaller. :

```
//Instantiate a JAXBContext
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class);

//Create a Binder
JAXBBinder binder = (JAXBBinder) context.createBinder();

//Create an standard unmarshaller to reuse its unmarshalListener
JAXBUnmarshaller standardUnmarshaller = (JAXBUnmarshaller) context.createUnmarshaller();

//Use reflection for setting the binder's unmarshallerListener (fest-reflect again)
XMLUnmarshaller unmarshaller = Reflection.field("unmarshaller").ofType(XMLUnmarshaller.class).in(binder.getXMLBinder()).get();
unmarshaller.setUnmarshalListener(standardUnmarshaller.getXMLUnmarshaller().getUnmarshalListener());

//my unmarshal callbacks are called now
MyObject myObject = binder.unmarshal(domDocument);
```

I guess the problem would be the same with the marshaling methods, but I did not investigate this case, as I don’t use marshal callbacks.

I tested the JAXB RI implementation of javax.xml.bind.Binder, and the callback methods are called correctly. Though, it is not an option for me to use the RI, because it does not preserve the comment nodes in the original DOM document.

Did I miss something in the configuration of Moxy, or is this a bug in the implementation ? If a bug, is there a simpler workaround than the one I used ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to confirm the issue that you are seeing.  You can use the following link to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/420753